# Swift 2.0 with Alamofire: How to send http headers with X-WSSE Authorization?

Tags: ios, swift, http-headers, alamofire

Here is my code:

```
>   let uuid: CFUUIDRef = CFUUIDCreate(nil)
    let nonce: CFStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuid)
    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let timestamp = NSDate()
    let secretKey = "DAqE6lBUgzxJRuR287GR"
    let username = "us_demo003"

    let formattedDate: String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timestamp)


    let text = String((nonce as String)+formattedDate+secretKey)

    let sha1 = text.sha1()

    let passwordDigest = sha1.toBase64()

    let headers = ["Username":username,"PasswordDigest": passwordDigest, "Nonce":(nonce as String), "Created":formattedDate]

    let theUrlString = "url here"

    manager.request(.GET, theUrlString, parameters: nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL, headers: theHeaders).responseJSON { (result) -> Void in
        print("BEGIN")
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nBEGIN\n\(result)\n\n\n\n\n\nEND")
        print("STOP")
    }
```

The result I'm getting is the following:

```
SUCCESS: {
data = "";
replyCode = 1;
replyText = "No Authentication Header";
```

}

How exactly do I send an authentication header with Alamofire?  I've checked the documentation on the github.  Something I'm not doing right.

Thanks

Comment: How is `manager` in your code? Some wrapper to Alamofire?

Comment: yah.  Manager is Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.  It is a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you want to create the `Authorization` header where `Authorization` is the dictionary key and `WWSE profile=\"username_token\"` is the value. Then you also need to set the `X-WSSE` header key to `UsernameToken Username="admin", PasswordDigest="buctlzbeVflrVCoEfTKB1mkltCI=", Nonce="ZmMzZDg4YzMzYzRmYjMxNQ==", Created="2014-03-22T15:24:49+00:00"`.

```
let token = "some generated token"

let headers = [
    "Authorization": "WWSE profile=\"\(token)\""
    "X-WSSE": "UsernameToken Username=\"admin\", PasswordDigest=\"buctlzbeVflrVCoEfTKB1mkltCI=\", Nonce=\"ZmMzZDg4YzMzYzRmYjMxNQ==\", Created=\"2014-03-22T15:24:49+00:00\""
]
```

More info about WSSE auth can be found [here](http://www.orocrm.com/documentation/index/current/cookbook/how-to-use-wsse-authentication).

Comment: Thanks cnoon! Appreciate it.  Going to give this a whirl.